# How do I declare a variable with the Blob data type

Tags: sql, mysql, swift, typescript, backend

So I am working on a project and need to process an image from an app to the backend and then to the mySQL server. I wrote this function to save the data in typescript:

```
const saveImage = async function saveData(email: string, image: Blob): Promise<null> {
    return new Promise<null>(((resolve, reject) => {
        const query = "INSERT INTO ProfilePics SET ?"

        const insertImage = {
            email: email,
            image: image
        }

        connection.query(query, insertImage, (err: MysqlError | null, result: OkPacket | null) => {
            if (err != null) {
                reject(err.message); return;
            }

            if (result != null) {
                if (result.affectedRows == 1) {
                    resolve(null); return;
                } else {
                    reject('Unknown error 1 saving data to database.'); return
                }
            } else {
                reject('Unknown error 2 saving data to database.'); return
            }
        });
    }));
};
```

The Blob keyword isnt even highlighted and its giving errors that Blob isn't the word that's expected. I wrote this function so that I am actually able to post the data from the app but it's not working at all:

```
router.post('/set-image', async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const image: Blob = req.body.image;
    const email: string | undefined =  req.app.locals.user.email;

    if (typeof  data !== 'Blob') {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'The data must be a Blob.' }); return;
    }

    if (email === undefined) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'You must sign in to do that' }); return;
    }

    try {
        await data_functions.saveData(email, image);
        res.status(200).json({ success: 'The image was submitted.' });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err }); return;
    }
});
```

does anyone know how I can declare these variables as a Blob datatype?